# passar variável para função jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso manipular o botão clicado dentro dessa função, como passar a variável btn para dentro dela?

```
$('.btn_excluir').on('click', function () {
    btn = $(this);
    swal_confirm('Deseja realmente excluir o registro?', function (btn) {
        console.log(btn);
    });
});
```

Comment: Retire o `btn` de dentro dos parênteses. Ele já foi definido antes da função `swal_confirm`.

Answer (score 0):

O `swal_confirm` não é o método correto para a utilizar o `SweetAlert`, segundo a documentação você precisa executar uma função somente se o botão OK for clicado como no exemplo abaixo.

---

**Exemplo**

```
swal({
    title: "Deseja deletar?",
    text: "Tem certeza que deseja deletar o registro?",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
    if (willDelete) {
        /* Chama a sua função para deletar */
        swal("Seu registro foi deletado!", {
            icon: "success",
        });
    } else {
        swal("Seu registro não foi deletado!");
    }
});
```

Comment: o metodo swal_confirm fui eu quem criou, e ele está funcionando, o problema era só passar o botão externo pra dentro do swal, e ele foi resolvido tirando a variavel btn dos parenteses.